What movie has characters singing about the Ed Sullivan Show?
A long time ago, I saw parts of a very strange movie on TV.  It appeared to either be in or take place in the same era as films like Singin' In The Rain, and like that film it too was a musical.  I specifically remember multiple references in the dialog and the musical numbers to The Ed Sullivan Show (I'm not sure why).  There were also some parts that contained animation where the actors would write things in the air with their fingers.  
It was really a pretty corny film from what I could tell, but it always stuck with me and I cannot remember the title or find any reference to it anywhere.  It's possible that it was an episode of some show, but I believe it was more likely a film.
Language: English
Country of Origin: Most likely USA.
Approximate Date: Unknown, and any guess on my part is pure speculation since the film could have been a period piece or a parody.  It appeared to take place somewhere between 1950 and 1960.

Sounds like you're after the colorful 1963 musical Bye Bye Birdie that stars Janet Leigh, Dick Van Dyke and many others, where Ed Sullivan and his show figure prominently into the plot:

Conrad Birdie is the biggest rock & roll star of the 60's ever to be drafted. Aspiring chemist and song writer Albert is convinced he can make his fortune and marry his girlfriend Rosie if he gets Conrad on the Ed Sullivan show to kiss a high school girl goodbye. Albert's mother will do anything to break him up with Rosie. Kim and Hugo, the high school steadies, live in Sweet Apple, Ohio where most of the action takes place.

It features some animation, like this scene where Van Dyke draws smiley faces and words with his finger (starting at 0:45):



